# Sitecore content editor redirects to Page not foud

Tags: sitecore

Due to some publishing issues i corrupted my local enviroment. Luckily i had backup which i restored and my local site was functioning well but, when i login to sitecore and choose any option from main page like **Content Editor or Desktop it redirects to page not found**.

I've tried to disable exceptions which redirect to page but they were of no use. And no logs are being created. Should i replace the entire wwwroot folder but, my wwwroot backup is 2 months old.

Or should i start from scratch and create a new sitecore site for same solution. I've compared my web.config,connection strings files they don't seem o have any problem.

Suggest what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to login but seems due to some permission issue you are not able to Content Editor/Desktop. Check permission on folders like identityserver(used for login)/your website(content editor and other CMS work), to start with you can try to give permission to your IIS User/Everyone (as shown in image), once it starts working you can be selective and change permission as per your need
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKBAZ.png)